# How to create a Regular Button with an Icon

Tags: c#, uwp

In C#/UWP, how to create a normal "Button" Xaml Control with an AppBarButton Icon?

For Example, I want to do something like this:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox  Grid.Column="0" Header="MyTextBox"/>
        <Button   Icon="find"
                  Background="{x:Null}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                  Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Or more specifically:

```
<Button Icon="find"  … />
```

(Except the Icon Property only works with an AppBarButton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Set the content of the button equal to:

```
<SymbolIcon Symbol="find">.
```

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox  Grid.Column="0" Header="MyTextBox"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" 
            Background="{x:Null}"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find"/>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```